# Is there a way to define a current quarter in R?

Tags: r, forecasting

I have written a small program in R, and when I get to this following line:

```
i=which(grepl(yyyy.q, Metrop$year))+1
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in grepl(yyyy.q, Metrop$year) : object 'yyyy.q' not found
```

I think maybe this is occurring because I haven't defined 2019.3 as the current "yyyy.q". And that is what I need to do in order to tell R to start forecasting according to my model. Does that seem like the likely problem? I thought that was the problem but have struggled to fix it.

Here is how I am defining things in the beginning of my program before I get to the actual model specification, I assume the full code isn't necessary, but happy to share if that helps.

```
Metrop<-Houston
name<-"National"
Metrop<-Metrop[Metrop$year>=1989.4,]
```

[Screenshot of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR1nR.png)

Thanks for you help. Happy to share any more code or data if necessary.